# Combine CSS class identifiers into new CSS class

Tags: css

I have a div with the following classes applied.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

I was wondering if its possible to combine them into a new CSS class for example

```
.my_format {
  col-lg-4; 
  col-md-6; 
  col-sm-12; 
  md-3 
}
```

so that I don't need to re-type the whole thing and make my html cleaner. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to select a div that has all 4 classes? Or are you looking to apply the styles of those 4 classes to another style?

Comment: I want to apply all 4 of them to a html elements. Im looking for a way to make html cleaner by using class="my_format" which should under the hood do the same as all 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your new class to the css classes you are already having

```
.my_format, .col-lg-4{}
.my_format, .col-md-6{}
.my_format, .col-sm-12{}
.my_format, .mb-3{}
```

Comment: Thanks. The css are from bootstrap.min.css, cannot really manually edit but exploring options to inherit/extend/combine them. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **scss** in this case. In scss, you can extend multiple css classes.

Check this out : https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/

**SCSS**

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-lg-4 {
  color: blue;
}

.my-format {
  @extend .col-lg-4, .col-md-6, .col-sm-12, .mb-3;
}
```

Here is a sample fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40847/

Comment: Thank you. I will have thorough look tomorrow.

Comment: Based on your comment to me above, a preprocessor like SASS or LESS is the way to go. In general, as you get into more complex CSS, a preprocessor is the way to go. It'll save you a bunch of time, far more organized, lets you set up variables and "functions" in a manner of speaking.